# Open google cloud console with a certain user account

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform

By default whenever you navigate to google cloud console it uses first *default* account. Is there a way to construct a link (for example) which would use a certain account from the list? I'm aware about different profiles and how make a default account. However, I'm rather interesting in making it works without need to log-off for default account.

Answer (score 6):

Found out just after posting that if you pass authuser=1 it will select second account from the list which is enough in my case:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=&authuser=1&folder=&organizationId=
```